# knife softlayer server create with monthly billing

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure, knife

I am trying to **create new VSI in Softlayer with monthly billing using knife softlayer plugin**, there is tag for that:

> --billing-monthly

but seems its now working. Also I tried as:

- '--billing-monthly'
- '--billing-monthly true'
- '--billing-monthly=true'

but nothting are working, it always creates hourly billed VSI

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue reported about that:

- [An hourly VSI is created instead of a Monthly server instance](https://github.com/softlayer/knife-softlayer/issues/29)

  It seems that the **bill_monthly** flag is not being considered in the code:
- https://github.com/softlayer/knife-softlayer/blob/master/lib/chef/knife/softlayer_server_create.rb#L65

I recommend to use a programming language or another way to order servers.

To see available programming languages suported by SoftLayer:

- [SoftLayer Development Network](http://sldn.softlayer.com/)

JIC:
Here an example using [Ruby Client](https://github.com/softlayer/softlayer-ruby), you need to **set hourly flag as false**:

- [Create a virtual server from an existing image template](https://softlayer.github.io/ruby/create_server_from_template/)